# Xtext DSL plugin only provides keyword suggestions for the first line of the file

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, dsl, xtext

I've been developing a DSL as an eclipse plugin using Xtext, and so far I was able to reach up to the point where the runtime eclipse application provides a list of suggestions when pressed Ctrl+space. However, the suggestions are only displayed for the first line of the file. Afterwards, no matter how many times I pressed Ctrl+space, suggestions will not come. Below is my Xtext grammar:

```
Domainmodel:
    (elements+=MainElement)
;

MainElement:
    ProjectionName | ProjectionComponent | LayerSpecification |
    Description | Capability | Category | ServiceGroup |
    IncludeFragment | {MainElement} Override | {MainElement} Overtake
;

ProjectionName:
    'projection' modelName=ID ';'
;

ProjectionComponent:
    'component' componentName=ID ';'
;

LayerSpecification:
    'layer' layerName=ID ';'
;

Description:
    'description' string=STRING ';'
;

Capability:
    'capability' type=('Online' | 'Offline') ';'
;

Category:
    'category' type=('Integration' | 'ExternalB2B' | 'Users') ';'
;

ServiceGroup:
    'servicegroup' type=('Mobility' | 'Reporting') ';'
;

IncludeFragment:
    ('@Dynamic_Component_Dependency' componentName=ID) 'include' 'fragment' fragmentToIncludeName=ID ';'
;

Override:
    '@Override'
;

Overtake:
    '@Overtake'
;
```

I have also tried another simpler example (mentioned below) which does not have this problem: -

```
Domainmodel:    (elements+=MainElement)* ;

MainElement:    FileName | Type  ;

Type:   Component | Layer | Description | Category | Entity | Comment ;

FileName:   'projection' name=ID ';' ;

Component:  'component' name=ID ';' ;

Layer:  'layer' name=ID ';' ;

Description:    'description' string=STRING ';' ;

List:   Users | Developers ;

Users:  'Users' ;

Developers:     'Developers' ;

Category:   'category' lists=List ';' ;

Entity:     'entityset' name=ID 'for' name2=ID ';' ;

Comment:    '----------' comment=ID '----------' ;
```

Could anyone please help me with understanding why the mentioned problem happens to the first code and not the second?

Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second grammar uses a zero-to-many cardinality in the rule `Domainmodel:    (elements+=MainElement)* ;` whereas your first grammar appears to be missing the `*` sign `Domainmodel: (elements+=MainElement);`.

Fixing that one to `Domainmodel: (elements+=MainElement)*;` will help.

Comment: Thank You! I had missed the * symbol. :-)